# Laravel return data that matches two tables

Tags: php, laravel

i have two different tables like these:

Table:products

`id->1
name->pencil
siz->big`

Table:colours

`id->2
colour_name->red
product_id->1`

Here is my codes in controller;

```
$products= Product::where('active', 1);

if ($request->has('size')) {
   $products->whereIn('size', $request->input('size'));
}

$products= $products->paginate(10);

return view('pencil.index', compact("products"));
```

The results are filtered by request's size values. But the problem colours in different table, how can i do the correct query for colour filters ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent models or the Query builder directly? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do a simple leftJoin Product:leftJoin('colours', 'colours.product_id', 'products.id')->get();

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write, there is a second parameter from request colour. I don't know where to put request in query. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it nicely using Eloquent. So in your `Product` model class add this method:

```
public function colours()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Colour::class);
}
```

and in your `Colour` model:

```
public function product() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Then in your controller or wherever you have the business logic you can do it like so:

```
Product::where('id', $productId)->colours; // this gives you list of all the colours for that product.
```

Getting list of colours based on the colour name:

```
$colours = Colour::where(
   'colour_name', request('colour')
)->get();
```

then simply when iterating over the `$colours` you can use:

```
foreach($colours as $colour)
{
    // $colour->product; is what you are looking for.
}
```

--- EDIT

```
Product::with('colours', function($query) use ($colour) { 
    $query->where('colour_name', $colour);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i should start the colour query as follows $products-> . How can i do that ?

Comment: The way your relationship is setup you say "A product Has many colours". So just to be clear, is this your expectation?
Or do you want a "colour to have many products" ie 2 products can have 1 colour?

Comment: Yes you right, sorry I couldn't ask the question correctly. if I edit my question, will you look again ?

Comment: Yes, I am here :) I edited my answer as well, so see if that helps you somehow. But you have to add the methods I mentioned above in the models.

Comment: I try your last code but i got the error.This is my fault i immediately edit my question.

Comment: Please share the error that you are getting, I cannot help you without looking at what you are trying.

Comment: I still don't understand do you have many colours for a single product? Whenever you iterate in your view over the `$products` you can iterate over its colours like this: `$product->colours`. I really don't understand the logic here.

Comment: Yes i have many colours for a single product. In view blade have checkbox inputs, colours and sizes. When size (medium and big) checkbox is checked (medium), products are filtered by column value. But colours is different table, so i can't query.

Comment: You can query it the way I showed you. So put the `colours` function in your `Product` model, then for each product you can access the colours like this: `$product->colours`. And you can iterate over them in your view.

Comment: Finally i did it. Thank you for answers. Cheers !